# Upload csv file using mysql within popSQL

Tags: sql, mysql, csv, import-csv, popsql

I used the command line to load my csv file. I want to know how to import/upload it within popsql so I can write queries. The database is connected.

###### Command line code

```sql
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/anishachoudhury/Desktop/Anisha/mysql/school-closures-covid.csv' 
    -> INTO TABLE faceCoverings
    -> IGNORE 1 ROWS;
Query OK
```